# How to view device kernel information (verbose)?

Tags: system, kernel

I need to view my device kernel info, in particular the architectures.  The device is not rooted, therefore `uname` command isn't available in local terminal, but `cat /proc/version` doesn't have an option to increase verbosity (that I'm aware of) like `-a` for `uname`.  Is there any other method I can use to see this information?

Comment: What device are you using? In most phones I have used, uname is installed by default. What information about the architecture do you want to access?

Comment: The `getprop` command has a number of values that are related to the architecture. Check out `getprop | grep abi`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the architecture that you are looking in particular, then from the terminal you can type `arch` command.

You can also try [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z) to check the kernel architecture on its System tab.

Note : The assumption that uname is only found on rooted devices is unfounded. I have a device not rooted on Android 8.1 that has uname thanks to toybox.

Comment: `arch` is not available via adb on my phone (Sony XA2, Android 9).

Comment: @Robert toybox is not installed on your phone? Or is toybox installed but arch has not been packaged with it?

Comment: Arctiic's question is about an unrooted device. Mine is unrooted, too. Therefore of course "toybox" is not installed. Installing such executables system wide plus PATH require a rooted device.

Comment: @Robert I think `toolbox` and `toybox` are part of stock Android, how would you get `getprop` and `setprop` without them. Nothing restricts apps executing `/system/bin/uname -m` or the `uname` syscall (including SELinux and seccomp). Also `uname` is part of every `busybox` release. Get one with Termux or place in `/data/local/tmp` and execute from `adb shell`. Multiple options.

Comment: @Irfan OK, you are right, there is a toybox and toolbox, however neither of them supports `arch` on my device (Sony XA2, Android 9 security update 2019-08-01).

Comment: @Robert same here. Busybox does have; it's also a wrapper over `uname` syscall.